# Asynchronous constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, constructor

How can I best handle a situation like the following?

I have a constructor that takes a while to complete.

```
var Element = function Element(name){
   this.name = name;
   this.nucleus = {};

   this.load_nucleus(name); // This might take a second.
}

var oxygen = new Element('oxygen');
console.log(oxygen.nucleus); // Returns {}, because load_nucleus hasn't finished.
```

I see three options, each of which seem out of the ordinary.

**One**, add a callback to the constructor.

```
var Element = function Element(name, fn){
   this.name = name;
   this.nucleus = {};

   this.load_nucleus(name, function(){
      fn(); // Now continue.
   });
}

Element.prototype.load_nucleus(name, fn){
   fs.readFile(name+'.json', function(err, data) {
      this.nucleus = JSON.parse(data); 
      fn();
   });
}

var oxygen = new Element('oxygen', function(){  
   console.log(oxygen.nucleus);
});
```

**Two**, use EventEmitter to emit a 'loaded' event.

```
var Element = function Element(name){
   this.name = name;
   this.nucleus = {};

   this.load_nucleus(name); // This might take a second.
}

Element.prototype.load_nucleus(name){
   var self = this;
   fs.readFile(name+'.json', function(err, data) {
      self.nucleus = JSON.parse(data); 
      self.emit('loaded');
   });
}

util.inherits(Element, events.EventEmitter);

var oxygen = new Element('oxygen');
oxygen.once('loaded', function(){
   console.log(this.nucleus);
});
```

**Or three**, block the constructor.

```
var Element = function Element(name){
   this.name = name;
   this.nucleus = {};

   this.load_nucleus(name); // This might take a second.
}

Element.prototype.load_nucleus(name, fn){
   this.nucleus = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(name+'.json'));
}

var oxygen = new Element('oxygen');
console.log(oxygen.nucleus)
```

But I haven't seen any of this done before.

What other options do I have?

Comment: Blocking the constructor means blocking ***everything***, so I probably wouldn't do that.

Comment: Options 1, and 2 are effectively the same approach. You pass a load handler to the constructor, and that handler is triggered from within the readFile callback. This is how event-based programming works (which is what JavaScript/Node is). You can use option 1, or 2, or any other variation on the theme, but effectively you get the same asynchronous behavior.

Comment: I learnt much more things from this "question" than given answers. +1 for "informative question"!

Comment: Just one things. Use `.once()` not `.on()` for this case. It's sementically better :).

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do it blocking with ES6 Classes, is that possible? Thank you

Comment: @DiegoRBaquero You should’t block.  Use promises instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given the necessity to avoid blocking in Node, the use of events or callbacks isn't so strange<sup>(1)</sup>.

With a slight edit of Two, you could merge it with One:

```
var Element = function Element(name, fn){
    this.name = name;
    this.nucleus = {};

    if (fn) this.on('loaded', fn);

    this.load_nucleus(name); // This might take a second.
}

...
```

Though, like the `fs.readFile` in your example, the core Node APIs (at least) often follow the pattern of static functions that expose the instance when the data is ready:

```
var Element = function Element(name, nucleus) {
    this.name = name;
    this.nucleus = nucleus;
};

Element.create = function (name, fn) {
    fs.readFile(name+'.json', function(err, data) {
        var nucleus = err ? null : JSON.parse(data);
        fn(err, new Element(name, nucleus));
    });
};

Element.create('oxygen', function (err, elem) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(elem.name, elem.nucleus);
    }
});
```

---

(1) It shouldn't take very long to read a JSON file. If it is, perhaps a change in storage system is in order for the data.

Answer (score 29):

Update 2:
Here is an updated example using an asynchronous factory method. N.B. this requires Node 8 or Babel if run in a browser.

```
class Element {
    constructor(nucleus){
        this.nucleus = nucleus;
    }

    static async createElement(){
        const nucleus = await this.loadNucleus();
        return new Element(nucleus);
    }

    static async loadNucleus(){
        // do something async here and return it
        return 10;
    }
}

async function main(){
    const element = await Element.createElement();
    // use your element
}

main();
```

Update:
The code below got upvoted a couple of times. However I find this approach using a static method much better:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24686979/2124586

ES6 version using promises

```
class Element{
    constructor(){
        this.some_property = 5;
        this.nucleus;

        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            this.load_nucleus().then((nucleus) => {
                this.nucleus = nucleus;
                resolve(this);
            });
        });
    }

    load_nucleus(){
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => resolve(10), 1000)
        });
    }
}

//Usage
new Element().then(function(instance){
    // do stuff with your instance
});
```

Comment: The most elegant one.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398699/is-it-bad-practice-to-have-a-constructor-function-return-a-promise

Comment: the weird thing about this is that your constructor doesn't return the instance, it returns a promise to the instance, which is a bit confusing for an OOP pattern.

Comment: I agree. These days I would probably go for an async static function that loads the data and then returns instances with the data populated.

Comment: An async factory method is the best solution for such cases. A constructor should always return an instance of the class. Even a promise for an instance of the class is not good enough.

Answer (score 4):

I have developed an async constructor:

```
function Myclass(){
 return (async () => {
     ... code here ...
     return this;
 })();
}

(async function() { 
 let s=await new Myclass();
 console.log("s",s)
})();
```

- [async returns a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [arrow functions pass 'this' as is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- it is possible to return something else when doing new (you still get a new empty object in this variable. if you call the function without new. you get the original this. like maybe window or global or its holding object).
- it is possible to return the return value of called async function using await.
- to use await in normal code, need to wrap the calls with an async anonymous function, that is called instantly. (the called function returns promise and code continues)

**my 1st iteration was:**

maybe just add a callback

call an anonymous async function, 
then call the callback.

```
function Myclass(cb){
 var asynccode=(async () => { 
     await this.something1();
     console.log(this.result)
 })();

 if(cb)
    asynccode.then(cb.bind(this))
}
```

**my 2nd iteration was:**

let's try with a promise instead of a callback. 
I thought to myself: strange a promise returning a promise, and it worked. ..  so the next version is just a promise.

```
function Myclass(){
 this.result=false;
 var asynccode=(async () => {
     await new Promise (resolve => setTimeout (()=>{this.result="ok";resolve()}, 1000))
     console.log(this.result)
     return this;
 })();
 return asynccode;
}


(async function() { 
 let s=await new Myclass();
 console.log("s",s)
})();
```

**callback-based for old javascript**

```
function Myclass(cb){
 var that=this;
 var cb_wrap=function(data){that.data=data;cb(that)}
 getdata(cb_wrap)
}

new Myclass(function(s){

});
```

Comment: Why has this been downvoted with no explanation? It is a significant attempt to provide a workable solution to the stated problem. If you downvote because you think this approach will lead to problems then explain your concern in comments.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could do is preload all the nuclei (maybe inefficient; I don't know how much data it is). The other, which I would recommend if preloading is not an option, would involve a callback with a cache to save loaded nuclei. Here is that approach:

```
Element.nuclei = {};

Element.prototype.load_nucleus = function(name, fn){
   if ( name in Element.nuclei ) {
       this.nucleus = Element.nuclei[name];
       return fn();
   }
   fs.readFile(name+'.json', function(err, data) {
      this.nucleus = Element.nuclei[name] = JSON.parse(data); 
      fn();
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad code design.

The main problem is in the callback your instance it's not still execute the "return", this is what I mean

```
var MyClass = function(cb) {
  doAsync(function(err) {
    cb(err)
  }

  return {
    method1: function() { },
    method2: function() { }
  }
}

var _my = new MyClass(function(err) {
  console.log('instance', _my) // < _my is still undefined
  // _my.method1() can't run any methods from _my instance
})
_my.method1() // < it run the function, but it's not yet inited
```

So, the good code design is to explicitly call the "init" method (or in your case "load_nucleus") after instanced the class

```
var MyClass = function() {
  return {
    init: function(cb) {
      doAsync(function(err) {
        cb(err)
      }
    },
    method1: function() { },
    method2: function() { }
  }
}

var _my = new MyClass()
_my.init(function(err) { 
   if(err) {
     console.error('init error', err)
     return
   } 
   console.log('inited')
  // _my.method1()
})
```

Comment: This is what I do. I came here searching for a better pattern but haven't seen one yet.

Answer (score 1):

I extract out the async portions into a fluent method. By convention I call them together.

```js
class FooBar {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = "foo";
  }
  
  async create() {
    this.bar = await bar();

    return this;
  }
}

async function bar() {
  return "bar";
}

async function main() {
  const foobar = await new FooBar().create(); // two-part constructor
  console.log(foobar.foo, foobar.bar);
}

main(); // foo bar
```

I tried a static factory approach wrapping `new FooBar()`, e.g. `FooBar.create()`, but it didn't play well with inheritance. If you extend `FooBar` into `FooBarChild`, `FooBarChild.create()` will still return a `FooBar`. Whereas with my approach `new FooBarChild().create()` will return a `FooBarChild` and it's easy to setup an inheritance chain with `create()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can run constructor function with async functions synchronously via [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs). Here is an example to illustrate:

index.js (main app logic):

```
var nsynjs = require('nsynjs');
var modules = {
    MyObject: require('./MyObject')
};

function synchronousApp(modules) {
    try {
        var myObjectInstance1 = new modules.MyObject('data1.json');
        var myObjectInstance2 = new modules.MyObject('data2.json');

        console.log(myObjectInstance1.getData());
        console.log(myObjectInstance2.getData());
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("Error",e);
    }
}

nsynjs.run(synchronousApp,null,modules,function () {
        console.log('done');
});
```

MyObject.js (class definition with slow constructor):

```
var nsynjs = require('nsynjs');

var synchronousCode = function (wrappers) {
    var config;

    // constructor of MyObject
    var MyObject = function(fileName) {
        this.data = JSON.parse(wrappers.readFile(nsynjsCtx, fileName).data);
    };
    MyObject.prototype.getData = function () {
        return this.data;
    };
    return MyObject;
};

var wrappers = require('./wrappers');
nsynjs.run(synchronousCode,{},wrappers,function (m) {
    module.exports = m;
});
```

wrappers.js (nsynjs-aware wrapper around slow functions with callbacks):

```
var fs=require('fs');
exports.readFile = function (ctx,name) {
    var res={};
    fs.readFile( name, "utf8", function( error , configText ){
        if( error ) res.error = error;
        res.data = configText;
        ctx.resume(error);
    } );
    return res;
};
exports.readFile.nsynjsHasCallback = true;
```

Full set of files for this example could be found here: https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs/tree/master/examples/node-async-constructor

Comment: I didn't -1 you, but it is probably a good idea to mention that you are the author of the nsynjs library.