# not compile why you cannot identify the operator this error

Tags: typescript

The following code fraction does not compile why you cannot identify the operator **this** in your container class.

```
class MyComponent {
    public data: Array<Object>;
    public someAttribute: string;
    async​ ​constructor() {
        let info = await this.getData('http://localhost:8080/api/users')
        let check = function (data) {
            this.someAttribute = data.someAttribute
        }
        check(info)
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I see you are trying to access `this.getData`, but I don't see a definition for that anywhere...

Comment: You can't have an async constructor.

Comment: This doesn't look like ES6 code at all. Are you using Typescript?

Answer (score 2):

The first issue you have is that you're using `this` inside of a `function`. `this` inside of a `function` has a different meaning than what you are expecting. You want to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead:

```
let check = (data) => {
    this.someAttribute = data.someAttribute
}
```

The second issue I see is that you have flagged your `constructor` to be `async`. You cannot do that. Also, since you cannot `async` your `constructor`, that means you cannot `await` your `getData` function in your `constructor`. The right way to do this is to create an `init` function of some sort and do your `async` call there.

See this: [async constructor functions in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743426/async-constructor-functions-in-typescript)

Last, but not least, you have `this.getData`. You do not have a function called `getData` on your `MyComponent` class. That line will fail.

Example of how the meaning of `this` changes:

```js
class MyComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.someAttribute = 'test';
  }
}

class MyComponent2 {
  constructor() {
    ( function () {
      console.log('IIF Test');
      console.log('this', this); // undefined
      this.someAttribute = 'test'
    } ());
  }
}

console.log(new MyComponent().someAttribute); // Test
console.log(new MyComponent2().someAttribute); // Exception
```