# Chainable, Promise-based Class Interfaces in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, interface, constructor, promise, chainable

I am writing a constructor in JavaScript that has the following properties:

```
function WhizBang() {

   var promise;

   this.publicMethod_One = function publicMethod_One() { ... };
   this.publicMethod_Two = function publicMethod_Two() { ... };

   promise = asyncInit();
}
```

So, calling `new WhizBang()` will start the `asyncInit()` process. What isn't obvious from the code above is that none of the public methods in the interface should run until this call to `asyncInit()` has closed.

So, the definition of `publicMethod_One()` might look something like this:

```
function publicMethod_One() {

  promise
    .then( doStuff )
    .catch( reportInitFailure )
  ;

  function doStuff() { ... }
  function reportInitFailure() { ... }
}
```

Some of the things that happen in `doStuff()` are asynchronous; some of them aren't.

So, if an end user of my class did something like this:

```
function main() {

  var whizBang = new WhizBang();

  whizBang
    .publicMethod_One()
    .publicMethod_Two()
  ;
}
```

The call to `publicMethod_One()` musn't be made until `asyncInit()` has closed. And the call to `publicMethod_Two()` musn't be made until both `asyncInit()` and `publicMethod_One()` have closed.

How can I define my class methods so that they are chainable?

What I think I need to do is define a class whose public methods are all equivalent to calling `then()` on a promise, followed by class specific, implementation stuff.

Internets, halp!

( Bonus points for using the [Bluebird Promise Library](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) in your answer. )

Comment: Constructors that perform IO generally make me dizzy. I'd separate object creation and IO if possible.

Comment: See the second half of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227480/javascript-async-constructor-pattern/28228236#28228236) for why it's a generally bad idea to run async operations in constructors.  What you need to do is to return a promise for your async operation so that caller can know when it's done, but you can't return a promise from the constructor because the constructor has to return the object.  Much better to have an `.init()` method that returns a promise does the async part of the initialization and then you can wait on that promise before doing other stuff.

Comment: related: [Is it bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572)

Answer (score 4):

### What you have now

What you have now is actually pretty nice. Since you're caching the result of `asyncInit` in a promise and everyone waits for the same promise - it's impossible for any of the code in those functions to run before the promise has finished.

```
function publicMethod_One() {    
  promise // the fact you're starting with `promise.` means it'll wait
    .then( doStuff )
    .catch( reportInitFailure );
}
```

So rather than forcing people to wait in order to use `publicMethod_One` they already can call it right away and the methods like `doStuff` will only execute the promise has resolved.

### A fluid interface

Well, like you noticed your code has a major issue, there is no way for a given method to know when to run or a way to sequence methods - you can solve this in two ways:

- Create a fluid interface that returns `this` on every action and queues the promise.
- Return the promise from each async call.

Let's look at the two approaches:

#### Fluid interface

This means that all your methods return the instance, they must also queue so things don't happen 'at once'. We can accomplish this by modifying `promise` on each call:

```
function publicMethod_One() {    
  promise = promise // note we're changing it
    .then( doStuff )
    .catch( reportInitFailure );
  return this; // and returning `this`
}
```

You might also want to expose a `.ready` method that returns the current promise so the sequence of operations can be waited for from the outside:

```
function ready(){
    return this.promise;
}
```

This can enable things like:

```
var ready = new WhizBang().publicMethod_One().publicMethod_One().ready();
ready.then(function(){
     // whizbang finished all operations
}); // can also add error handler
```

#### Returning thenables

In my opinion this is the simpler approach, all your methods return the promise they create so they can individually be waited for:

```
function publicMethod_One() {    
  return promise // note we're returning and not changing it
    .then( doStuff )
    .catch( reportInitFailure );
}
```

This is nice because the async operation is exposed outside.

Chaining is possible since you're using bluebird with `.bind` as such:

```
var whiz = new WhizBang();
var res = Promise.bind(whiz).then(whiz.publicMethod_one)
                            .then(whiz.publicMethod_one);
res.then(function(){
     // all actions completed, can also use return values easier.
});
```

But the advantage is it easier to reason about from the outside - for this reason I prefer this approach personally. Personally I always prefer to `return` meaningful data than to change internal state.