# http json data prints to console but not to page in Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I know this is probably an easy solution.  I am building an Ionic 3 app and was able to connect to a json data file and print the objects to the console, but I am unable to pass the `item` to my search function. The error I get on the page is `Runtime Error - Cannot read property "filter" of undefined` - I am guessing its because the item isn't being made available.

**data.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

@Injectable()
export class Data {
  items: any;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.http
      .get("./assets/data/plaques.json")
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.items = data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }

  filterItems(searchTerm) {
    return this.items.filter(item => {
      return (
        item.veteran_first.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access `this.items` before it's been initialized.

http.get is an asynchronous function, and `this.items` may not be set when you access `filterItems`.

I highly recommend reading [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) which will go into greater understanding of the asynchronous nature of javascript.

Comment: This may also be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856778/asynchronous-constructor

Answer (score -1):

could you please wrap it with `zone()` like this :

```
this.zone.run(() => {
   this.items = data;
 });
```