# Async constructor via static function, but await doesn't work

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, constructor

I've created a simple user class with a username, hashedpassword and passwordsalt.
Because the hashing and salting of takes some time, I decided to create a static async function to create a new user ([Asynchronous constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856778/asynchronous-constructor)). But somehow when I call this static async function to create a new user, the await doesn't wait for the createUser to finish. Does anybody know why?

```
  console.log(1);
  var newUser = await User.createUser(newUserJson);
  console.log(3);
  console.log(newUser.getPasswordHash());  //<- this line fails with the error that it cannot do the .getPasswordHash on undefined.


static async createUser(jsonUser) {
    var password = jsonUser.password;
    const saltRounds = 10;
    try {
      bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
          jsonUser.passwordHash = hash;
          jsonUser.passwordSalt = salt;

          var us = new User(jsonUser);  //nonblocking. Just sets some fields.
          console.log(2);
          return us;
        });
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error')
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

My console output shows 1, 3, 2...

Does anybody know why `newUser.getPasswordHash()` doesn't wait for `var newUser = await User.createUser(newUserJson)`; ?

Comment: It does, but `createUser` doesn't wait for `bcrypt.genSalt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pretty much sums up the confusion on `async/await`. You seem to think you need to make something as `async` in order to `await` it. It's actually the **opposite**, since you mark as `async` in order to *"contain"* methods which you intend to `await`. So as said, you need `bcrypt.genSalt`  and `bcrypt.hash` both to be wrapped in a `Promise`.

There's libraries to do that, or you can just roll it with the "vanilla" functions already included. And then of course you are trapping exceptions in the wrong place as well:

```
static createUser(jsonUser) {
    const { password } = jsonUser;
    const saltRounds = 10;

    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => 
      bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, (err, salt) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(salt);
      })
    ).then(salt => new Promise((resolve,reject) => 
        bcrypt.hash(password, salt, (err, hash) => {
          if (err) reject(err);

          jsonUser.passwordHash = hash;
          jsonUser.passwordSalt = salt;

          var us = new User(jsonUser);
          resolve(us);
        })
    );
}
```

Or if you *"really want"* to use an `await` instead of chaining the promises with `.then()`, that's when you mark with `async`:

```
static async createUser(jsonUser) {                  // marked as async
    const { password } = jsonUser;
    const saltRounds = 10;

    let salt = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => // because we await here
      bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, (err, salt) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(salt);
      })
    );

    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => 
        bcrypt.hash(password, salt, (err, hash) => {
          if (err) reject(err);

          jsonUser.passwordHash = hash;
          jsonUser.passwordSalt = salt;

          var us = new User(jsonUser);
          resolve(us);
        })
    );
}
```

So it's just defining a function that returns a `Promise`, and nothing more magical than that.

Then on course you actually use your `await` to get the value "within" a block which is marked `async`, and of course do the exception handling there instead. Juts using an IIFE here for demonstration:

```
(async function() {  // async marks the block

    try { 
      console.log(1);
      var newUser = await User.createUser(newUserJson);  // where you can await
      console.log(3);
      console.log(newUser.getPasswordHash());           // This is expected to be NOT async
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
    }

})()
```

So there is nothing magic here at all, and the `async/await` is simply "sugar" for calling `.then()` to get the resolved value of a `Promise`. But the functions themselves simply are are a `Promise` to return, and you only mark as `async` where the "inner block" of code actually calls an `await`.

Follow that and your fine, and of course if the `User.getPasswordHash()` was actually an "async" function itself, then you similarly want to return a `Promise` from that and then `await` the result:

```
 console.log(await newUser.getPasswordHash());
```

But if `new User()` is not async, then you likely don't have async sub-methods of that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just thought when I wrote the async before the static function. It would automatically return a promise with result the newly created user. So I assumed the await would work then.